# IP Address last octed with "_" character

Tags: ip, network-printer

I have an IP address of 192.xxx.xx.208_3  the last octet has an _3 what does this mean? It is a printer that I cannot ping. I want to add it to other computers but it does not list as a selectable printer.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the actual IP, and not the "Port name" of the port used to contact the printer?  Can you provide a screenshot of what's showing you the IP address in question?

Comment: I stand corrected. It is the port name.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing listed in the printer property dialog under "Port" is the name of assigned to the port, not the IP address.

Port names by default  auto generated from the IP address, and "_#" is added to avoid duplicates names when multiple ports point to the same IP.  You can also give them a custom name of whatever you'd like.

To find the actual IP (and other communication info), highlight the port in question and click "Configure Port".

This will open the port's properties dialog which will show you the actual IP address:

[image]